# German is called Deutsch in German language. How do you say "Tamil" in German?

Tags: standard-german

German is called Deutsch in German language. How do you say "Tamil" in German ?

Comment: What has the German word for German to do with the German word for Tamil?

Comment: Your question is a bit ill-advised. *Deutsch* means *[language] of the people*, while German is a term derived from Latin. We don't call ourselves Germans either. Only people from some other countries do. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Germany how people from other countries call Germany and German.

Answer (score 3):

A good source to find out how regions, places, languages or else are named in different languages is Wikipedia when multi-language articles are maintained.

There we find:

[தமிழ்](https://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D) linking to [Tamil](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil) in the German Wikipedia.

*Tamilisch* is also listed as a rarely used alternative name.